# URL rewrite using .htaccess (specific one)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

need help rewriting URL using .htaccess file. The new website lost the word "dovanos" in URL, and I want to save my customers and seo redirecting them to correct page.

I have few thousand URL's like these:

www.example.com/dovanos/category1/item1.html

www.example.com/dovanos/category1/item2.html

www.example.com/dovanos/category2/item1.html

www.example.com/dovanos/category2/item2.html

And so on. Need to rewrite them so, that they loose word "dovanos":

www.example.com/category1/item1.html

www.example.com/category1/item2.html

www.example.com/category2/item1.html

www.example.com/category2/item2.html

Could anybody help with these? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dovanos/(.*)\.html$ $1.html [R=301,L]
```